# Eliminate the Remove Duplicate msg in vba

Tags: excel, automation, macros, duplicates, vba

This has me stumped. In my vba code I am removing duplicates in a column using

```
Columns("AB:AB").Select
    Range("AB5").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("SFDC_Data").Select
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Range("E5").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=_
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("E2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Range("E5").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("E:E").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
```

The popup comes up making me confirm before it will perform the duplicate removal.  How can I get rid of that popup or automatically confirm it?

Any help?! I have tried all kinds of things including,

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Please Help!

Comment: The one line you are showing should not incite a confirmation popup.  Please post more of the code.

Comment: `Columns("E:E").Select
    Range("E5").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("E:E").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes`

Comment: Please post the code in the original post with edit.  The comments cannot be properly formatted.

Comment: Does this help?  I know it is very basic code.  The idea is to remove duplicates in column E.  The popup I can't get rid of is basic for "remove duplicates", saying how many duplicates and unique values.  It basically asks me to confirm before performing the operation.

Comment: Also, you will need to show even more. None of those lines would throw a confirmation.

Comment: Try without the `Array(1)`.  Just use `Columns:=1`

Comment: I get no popup with the code you have provided.  Can you show the entire sub.

Comment: By Taking out the Array, it does not perform any task for me.  It just highlights the column.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get any pop-ups when I remove duplicates with VBA. Try adding these two lines before and after your block of code:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

I've used this pair on several occasions for other things and it always does the trick.